# Content-Type must be 'application/json-patch+json' JsonServiceClient ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to perform a patch with a JsonServiceClient to a service stack api as follows:

```
var patchRequest = new JsonPatchRequest
{
    new JsonPatchElement
    {
        op = "replace",
        path = "/firstName",
        value = "Test"
    }
};
_jsonClient.Patch<object>($"/testurl/{id}", patchRequest);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Content-Type must be 'application/json-patch+json'

The error is clear. Is there a way to change the content type before perform the request for the JsonServiceClient?

This is the request POCO in the ServiceStack api:

```
[Api("Partial update .")]
[Route("/testurl/{Id}”, "PATCH")]
public class PartialTest : IReturn<PartialTestRequestResponse>, IJsonPatchDocumentRequest,
    IRequiresRequestStream
{
    [ApiMember(Name = “Id”, ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}

public class PartialTestRequestResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Service implementation:

```
public object Patch(PartialTest request)
    {
        var dbTestRecord = Repo.GetDbTestRecord(request.Id);

        if (dbTestRecord == null) throw HttpError.NotFound("Record not found.");

        var patch =
          (JsonPatchDocument<TestRecordPoco>)
              JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.GetRawBody(), typeof(JsonPatchDocument<TestRecordPoco>));

        if (patch == null)
            throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Body is not a valid JSON Patch Document.");

        patch.ApplyTo(dbTestRecord);
        Repo.UpdateDbTestRecord(dbTestRecord);
        return new PartialTestResponse();
    }
```

I'm using Marvin.JsonPatch V 1.0.0 library.

Comment: This is not an error that's in ServiceStack, please update your post to include the ServiceStack Service implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still not clear where the Exception is coming from as it's not an Error within ServiceStack. If you've registered a Custom Format or Filter that throws this error please include its impl (or a link to it) as well as the full StackTrace which will identify the source of the error.

But you should never call `Patch<object>` as an `object` return type doesn't specify what Response Type to deserialize into. Since you have an `IReturn<T>` marker you can just send the Request DTO:

```
_jsonClient.Patch(new PartialTest { ... });
```

Which will try to deserialize the Response in the `IReturn<PartialTestRequestResponse>` Response DTO. But as your Request DTO implements `IRequiresRequestStream` it's saying you're expecting unknown bytes that doesn't conform to a normal Request DTO, in which case you likely want to use a raw HTTP Client like [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils), e.g:

```
var bytes = request.Url.SendBytesToUrl(
  method: HttpMethods.Path,
  requestBody: jsonPatchBytes,
  contentType: "application/json-patch+json",
  accept: MimeTypes.Json);
```

You could modify the ContentType of a JSON Client using a request filter, e.g:

```
_jsonClient.RequestFilter = req => 
    req.ContentType = "application/json-patch+json";
```

But it's more appropriate to use a low-level HTTP Client like HTTP Utils for non-JSON Service Requests like this.

Comment: You are right, It's a custom typed request filter that is throwing the error, is not SeviceStack

Comment: This filter is verifying for requestDTO that implements the interface IJsonPatchDocumentRequest, is not SeviceStack. Finally I used the Http Util string.SendStringToUr to send the request. Thank you ver much for your help!